# Copying vs creating a file using C#

Tags: c#

We have a web service that creates a folder structure for our projects and as part of the this I need to create a text file that has the path to the project. I've created a template text file with a dummy path that I will replace when creating the file. e.g

```
//XXXXXXXX/projects/
```

Now the question is, what is the optimal way to create the file on a network share from my template and update the path? I think I have two options:

1. open template file, get content as a string, replace the xxxxxxxx and then create a new text file on the network share
2. copy the template file to the network share, open, get the content as a string, replace the xxxxxxxx and save back

Comment: Why do you need to create a template file? If the file only has the project path, you can create a new text file after creating the directories.

Comment: @Kami the file actually has more than just the path but its not relevant to the question.  I need to either copy or write a file as stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is primarily opinion-based, but here goes:

I'd go for option #1, simply because (a) the two options are not that different and do not pose any significantly different technical "challenges", and (b) with option #1 you never run into the problem of having a file that points to an illegal path.